# How to hide a field group fieldset programmatically in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, users, entities

I have a [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) fieldset named **`group_p_payment`** as machine name. I want to hide this based on the user. I tried the following code:

```
        $user = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
        if(!in_array("Administrator", $user) ||  !in_array("administer", $user)) {
         $form['group_p_payment']['#access'] = FALSE;
        }
```

But it didn't work it. How can I hide the fieldset?

Comment: Also field_set id not visible in drupal 8 , unlike in drupal 6 which is visible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The field group module is no longer storing grouped fields as a fieldset in Drupal 8. It's storing metadata on each group in an array called `#fieldgroups` which is used in a pre-render function.

The logic of the module doesn't render the fieldset if all its children elements aren't visible. Hence, you can hide all the children elements to have the same effect. For example:

```
foreach ($form['#fieldgroups']['group_p_payment']->children as $form_element_id) {
  $form[$form_element_id]['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

The logic will have to change if you have nested groups, but the approach will remain the same.

Note that the above code can go in a form alter, but you should ensure that your form alter runs after Field Group does its work.

Here is complete working code, for a module named example in the `example.module` file:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function example_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_alter' && isset($implementations['example'])) {
    $hook_implementation = $implementations['example'];
    unset($implementations['example']);
    $implementations['example'] = $hook_implementation;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() for node_form.
 */
function example_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach ($form['#fieldgroups']['group_b_payment']->children as $form_element_id) {
    $form[$form_element_id]['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: When i give like this i have to give all element id's of the group inside the loop. Instead i tried **unset($form['#fieldgroups']['group_p_payment']** in the form alter.  That worked , but give some notice error in field_group.module

Comment: Thanks your solution works without any notice (without any modification in module file ;) ) .

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: #fieldgroups...` on a form with tabs. Thoughts?

Comment: It's a notice, wrap your code in an `isset` check if you need more robust logic, or ignore it.

Comment: "but you should ensure that your form alter runs after Field Group does its work." - how?