# How to programatically hide node field on viewing?

Tags: nodes, 9

Using Drupal 9,

How do I hide a node field when viewing it?

Let's say I have field `info`. I would like to conditionally not display the label or the value.

I assume I use hook_node_view_alter but I'm not familiar with how to manipulate the build render array.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide a field group fieldset programmatically in drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210791/how-to-hide-a-field-group-fieldset-programmatically-in-drupal-8)

Comment: Based on that link I would use unset(). I'd like to know what hook function to use and how to reference the field I want to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the **hook_preprocess**. If its on the specific entity such as the case of a paragraph it will look something like this where I am hiding some labels from a view based on some condition:

```
function [MODULE_NAME]_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables){
    $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
    // Get the parent bundle.
    $parentBundle = $paragraph->getParentEntity()->bundle();
    //check View type
    if ($parentBundle && $parentBundle == 'category_views') {
      if ($variables['content']['field_language_name']['#object']->get('field_language_name')->value != 'English') {
       //Removing labels
        unset($variables['content']['field_language_name']);
        unset($variables['content']['field_language']);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the key here is to use this in a hook_preprocess function:

        unset($variables['content']['field_language_name']);
        unset($variables['content']['field_language']);

Comment: I used **hook_preprocess_node** and **unset($variables['content']['field_info'])** to hide it.